# Is it offensive to call someone as "mister"?

Tags: honorifics

I watched American TV shows all the time. Sometimes this kind of scene appeared.

A: Hi, can I meet Mr. Smith?
B: It's **Judge** Smith

or

A: Mr. Smith, do you believe........
B: It's **Doctor** Smith

It also happened with people with military ranks. I found that people are offended with being called "Mister". Is it always the case in the real world?

Comment: Not offensive at all but if you are an MD and you are talking to a patient, you want to be addressed as Dr. X.  If you are a General, and you're on duty, you want to be called Gerneral X, not Mr X..

Comment: Of course, surgeons (at least in Britain) actually have the honorific title Mister, even if they have a "real" doctorate in surgery.

Comment: However, every person will be different. I'm not sure that this is anything actually to do with the English language, as the same question can be asked in any country and get the same answer: every person will be different. Some will mind, some will not.

Comment: @Andrew Leach - Isn't that only for consultants? P.S. What do they call female surgeons?

Comment: It's probably not a good idea to call that female police officer who's writing you a speeding ticket "mister".

Comment: “Mister” as a form of address rather than an honorific followed by a name is likely to be offensive.

Comment: In India, if one's profession/title is not known, he is addressed Mr., like Mr. Pillai. If Mr. Pillai is actually a professor, he may be called Prof. Pillai, but only by his equivalent. If a junior staff calls him Prof. Pillai, or Hello Professor, he should be sure that the professor is fine being called so, which many are not. Hence, the easy and safe way is to blindly use Mr. for men and Ms for women in general. Subordinates choose Sir and Madam. None use the full word 'Mister' but 'Mr.'

Comment: @chasly-supportsMonica No: it's essentially the same system as for medical doctors and dentists (where registration gets you the title). Female surgeons are called Mrs, even if they're unmarried or have a doctorate.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it's not about the English *language.* If a specific instance can be cited (rather than just "Is it always the case?") then such a question may be suitable for [interpersonal.SE].

Answer (score 1):

It is never offensive but it can be improper, especially when the person is a magistrate in the execution of their duties. When the person is a judge and   you are trying to obtain an appointment with him/her the personnel whom you contact will usually abide by this rule and remind you that you should do so, although often in an implicit recommendation, such as a simple and mild correction of your unknowing "mister Smith" by a "judge Smith". You should always refer to them as "judge" when you mention them to other people in formal business; moreover, even when talking casually people often refer naturally to judges, generals and other persons in high positions by mentioning their function before their name.
If the person is a doctor, even while in their practice, they will not insist on being addressed to as "doctor" but it is an enduring custom to do so and if you do not offend them by calling them "Mister", you might displease some of them.

Comment: +1 for wise advice.